# Pass array from one php page to another php page

Tags: php, arrays

i am writing a code on PHP and i want to pass an array of five to another php page. i have seen many examples but can't quite get it right though. give some suggestion on how to pass an array from one php page to another php page.

```
$name = array("asif", "john", "muzi", "faisal", "albert");
```

Comment: Use one of the http method to pass it ? May require the array to be serialized. Or you can use session.

Comment: any link or example that can enhance your answer? i'll be glad.